# access violation segmentation fault error in my "C" code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, access-violation

```
int sumH(int *arr, int var, int row) {
    if(var > 7) return(0);
    return( arr[(row*8 - 8) + var] + sumH(arr, var+1, row) );
}
```

the code above is the "buggy" code.

I have a declared array:

```
int array[64] = { some numbers here };
int *ptr = array; //pointer to array
sumH(ptr, 0, 1);  //call to the buggy function
```

after calling this function I get this error: 
**Access Violation, Segmentation Fault**

Comment: int array[64] = { 64 random numbers here }

Comment: And you pass it into that function as simply `sumH(array, 0, 1)` and that causes the segfault?

Comment: As a side question, why are your rows one-indexed and your columns zero-indexed?

Comment: no, I have created a pointer to that array, which is passed to the function.

Comment: @Dan , I believe it works fine. For `row = 1`,  it gives `arr[0 + var]`.
`var = 0` is the first element of the row. It has 8 elements, so basically when `var = 8` the condition is met, so it returns 0.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I think will help. I wasn't saying that your unusual indexing would not work, but it could be confusing to people who expect everything to be zero indexed.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: The code you gave compiles and runs just fine for me.  Are you _sure_ that's the code that's problematic?  How did you determine that?

Answer (score 0):

You state you declare:

```
int array[64] = { 64 random numbers here }
```

And then pass:

```
sumH(&array, 0, 1)
```

What you are actually passing is a pointer to the array, which is effectively a pointer to a pointer to the first element. You then try to dereference that pointer plus one, which is incorrect. You can either pass in the array itself:

```
sumH(array, 0, 1)
```

Or modify your function like so:

```
return( (*arr)[(row*8 - 8) + var] + sumH(arr, var+1, row) );
```

Comment: I declare `int array[64] = { some numbers here} `

then `int *ptr = array` 
then call `sumH(ptr, 0, 1)`
and i get the above mentioned error

Comment: Re: "What you are actually passing is a pointer to the array, which is effectively a pointer to a pointer to the first element. You then try to dereference that pointer plus one": true. Re: "which is incorrect": false. If `arr` points to the first element of an array, then `arr[1]` is a perfectly valid way to refer to the second element.

Comment: But if *arr points to the first element of an array, then arr[1] is not a way to refer to the second element, because **arr is the first element, and *(*arr+1) is the second element. arr[1] is *(arr+1).

Comment: @Dan: Ah, sorry, I misread "a pointer **to a pointer** to the first element". In that case, your mistake was earlier than I thought. In C, if you declare `array` as `int array[64]`, then `&array` points to the array, i.e., it points to the memory location holding first element. It does *not* point to some memory location that holds a pointer to the first element. (I suspect you're being misled by the common claim that an array "is just" a pointer to its first element. There are a lot of reasons for this claim, and I wouldn't simply dismiss it, but it's not literally true.)

Comment: ruakh - you're right in practice. I got confused when the questioner said "a pointer to the array". I took that to mean a pointer to array, but what he really meant to say was a pointer to the array's first element.

Comment: @Dan: O.K., but your answer is wrong. Your answer says that if you declare `int array[64] = { 64 random numbers here }`, and then pass `sumH(&array, 0, 1)`, then you're effectively passing a pointer to a pointer to the first element. This is completely wrong, regardless of what the OP did or did not mean. `&array` in this case is effectively *a pointer to the first element*. Furthermore, you contrast `sumH(&array, 0, 1)` with `sumH(array, 0, 1)` in this respect, even though they're actually roughly equivalent here. You should edit your answer to remove or correct the wrong statements.

Comment: (I should note, for completeness' sake, that `array` decays to what is genuinely a pointer to the first element, whereas `&array` is a pointer to the *entire* array. So in terms of bits at run-time, they both contain the address of the same memory location, but in terms of compile-time type-checking, the former denotes `sizeof(int)` bytes at that location, whereas the latter denotes `64 * sizeof(int)` bytes at that location.)